# Updating State from ObservableObject publisher

Tags: swift, swiftui, reactive-programming, swift5

I was experimenting with Combine and SwiftUI but stuck in updating state basically I want to update my state in the view every time ObservableObject changes, 
here's the example.

```
class XViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tVal: Bool = false
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func change() {
        Just(true)
            .delay(for: 3.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.tVal, on: self)
            .store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }
}
```

I have viewModel and one publisher and delayed publisher which triggers after 3 seconds.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = XViewModel()
    @State var toggleVal: Bool = false
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        self.viewModel.$tVal
            .sink { newVal in
            print(newVal)
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)        

        self.viewModel
            .$tVal.assign(to: \.toggleVal, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)

        viewModel.change()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: self.$viewModel.tVal) {
                Text("Toggle")

            Toggle(isOn: self.$toggleVal) {
                Text("Toggle from View")
            }
    }

}
```

What I expected is

```
viewModel.Just triggers
viewModel.tVal publisher triggers
view.toggleVal state triggers 
updates UI
```

But it seems although everything is updated it doesn't update state. Is there any way to update State or it wasn't meant to be updated at all and I need to bind my views directly to the viewModel's tVal value which is publisher.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@State` is not ready in `init` to operate, use instead `.onReceive` as below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = XViewModel()
    @State var toggleVal: Bool = false
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        self.viewModel.$tVal
            .sink { newVal in
            print(newVal)
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)        

        viewModel.change()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: self.$viewModel.tVal) {
                Text("Toggle")

            Toggle(isOn: self.$toggleVal) {
                Text("Toggle from View")
            }
            .onReceive(self.viewModel.$tVal) { newVal in // << here !!
                self.toggleVal = newVal
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, yes I understand the state is not initialized yet